# Open playstore and land back to app against a custom link

Tags: android, google-play, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a problem that looks familiar but with a different use case.
I have an application in which I have a url like below
https://www.myWebLink.com/referral-id/xxx
where xxx can by any **user ID**.

**Note:** *This url is a sharable url, which is shared by any user, with it's own USER ID, so when a next user opens link, it will display USER ID of the user who shared URL.*

All I want to do is when user shares above **URL** and it's clicked, there are 2 possibilities, either application is already installed or not and there are 2 actions as well.

1 - If application is installed, it opens the application and user ID is populated in the field. (This point is working well, i have handled it through deeplinks)

2 - If application is not installed, it should land to **googleplay** and once user installs the application, it should land back to application with user ID populated into the field.

*For second point I am able to redirect user to **googleplay**, for that I have used **"firebase dynamic links"** but the only problem I am facing is, I have to define URLs in dynamic link template, but for my case a **URL** totally depends on the user (as it has unique **USER ID**).*

[image]

So my question would be how can I achieve the second part where once user installs the application from **googleplay**, it lands back to application with **user ID** populated.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Is your use case not covered by: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/web-to-app

Comment: @MorrisonChang half of it, I just want to know how would I make sure that a dynamic link, in my case https://www.website.com/id/xxx, will be handled for each user.

Comment: I think you need to set the regex: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429?hl=en&ref_topic=6386656 so that the `userID` is passed on. Also see: [Getting Started with Firebase Dynamic Links on Android-Youtube video](https://youtu.be/zra2DCd0DnY?t=611)